# What exactly viewport meta tag does in html?

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have recently started learning about html and css. In particular, I am learning the responsive web design. I studied that meta viewport tag is one of the first steps in creating a responsive web design. In particular, I am studying from this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Here, they have given two images of a website on mobile screens of with and without viewport tag. In the first without screen, the image doesn't adjust itself with the screen with. But in the latter image, the image adjusts itself. Now, I get this point. I thought of replicating this using the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="jeff.jpg">

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing sof</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't make the image change as i change the width. So, what's going on here?

I know, I can solve this issue by putting a css block of width:100% but I want to understand why viewport is not working that way it was mentioned on the website. Or am I missing any important piece?

Comment: I remember once my website on mobile viewing was still looking like a desktop view. I was missing the viewport stuff. When I added it, finally the site was looking like it should do on mobile. I may not know exactly, but it is useful.

Comment: From what i read, I know it is supposed to do something right but I am probably missing some key point here.

Comment: In the example from w3schools, `<img>` has `width` and `height` attributes, they are not in your code, it may explain the difference.

Comment: So, if i have to add height and width css property then what is point of meta tag?Sorry if this question is silly, but I am really confused with meta tags? I purposefully omitted that height and width property.

Comment: The `<style>` tag in that link is not for decoration purposes

Comment: This was my first question. I got a down vote. Please anyone mention the probable reasons why this might have happened. So, I can avoid making same in future. Thank you.

Comment: Take a closer look at the [source code](https://www.w3schools.com/css/example_withviewport.htm) of the example with viewport: It also has a `<style>img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}</style>` which is missing from your example and wouldn't work without it

Comment: Also, it says in the tutorial, under **Size Content to The Viewport**: _3. Use CSS media queries to apply different styling for small and large screens..._ - Responsive design doesn't happen automatically - You need to define the style using CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser's viewport is the area of the window in which web content can be seen.

The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value device-width, which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%.

The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded.

Now, for images to be responsive in nature, we should always use `viewport-relative units` i.e `%`

so, you should add

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

for the image to resize along with screen size. Hope it clarifies your doubt!

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A  viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

Comment: Thanks for answering but this doesn't help. Sorry.